# How to run a CURL command with CURL OPTIONS (Header type )in a cron job?

Tags: curl, cron

In crontab, I have a job which is executing a curl command. I am able to execute the curl commands without Header, like

```
*/10 * * * * curl "http://vmurugan.net:8080/eureka/v2/apps"  > /Users/vmuruganandam/Library/Tomcat/Registered_Apps.xml
```

But when I pass the Header(with Content Type) to curl, it does not work,please see below:

```
*/10 * * * * curl -s "http://vmurugan.net:8080/eureka/v2/apps" -H "Content-Type: application/json" > /Users/vmuruganandam/Library/Tomcat/Registered_Apps.json
```

I expect the results of curl execution in json format and it is necessary to pass the header info with content type.

Any Idea on how to make it work?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: does not work **HOW**? curl barfs on the -H option? You get an invalid response from the remote server?

Comment: I'm guessing the curl job's running under the same ID? If it's a different ID, then that could be a factor. you could also have multiple versions of curl installed, and whatever's in the cron user's path is different than whatever you were doing your own CLI testing from.

Comment: Marc, Thanks for the reply. There is no issue with the curl command in cron job. It seems to be working fine. I tried pinging other REST APIs in CRON. The issue is with the REST API Implementation. The REST API, which i was trying to "curl" in the above cron job, is supposed to Output in both XML and JSON format. But it has some issues with JSON format.